# Cronjob time and minute handling

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I am trying to create a cronjob that  follows these rules:

- Monday - Friday
- From 8:00 - 16:00
- Every 2nd minute

So basically it has to run Monday to Friday, Every second minute in the hours between 8 - 16.

At these times it has to run the following command: `node /var/www/myProject/src/server.js`

However, since I'm fairly new to both cron and ubuntu, in general, i was hoping that some of you might be able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*/2 8-16 * * 1-5
```

Since expression for corn is 
minute hour day(month) month day(week), the above expression should satisfy your needs.

So, run "crontab -e"

It would open a file in you add this line at the end,

```
*/2 8-16 * * 1-5  /usr/local/bin/node /var/www/myProject/src/server.js
```

Then save the file. That should do it.,

Comment: which part of this takes into acount monday to friday? (just so i can learn it better :) )

Comment: The '1-5' part. See [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#*/2_8-16_*_*_1-5).

Comment: @ChristianPekeler Thanks mate